# Catch exception in Kotlin async coroutines and stop propagating

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to catch an exception that is thrown from async coroutines.
The following code demonstrates a problem:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    try {
        println(failedConcurrentSum())
    } catch (e: ArithmeticException) {
        println("Computation failed with ArithmeticException")
    }
}

suspend fun failedConcurrentSum() = coroutineScope {
    try {
        val one = async {
            try {
                delay(1000L)
                42
            } finally {
                println("First child was cancelled")
            }
        }

        val two = async<Int> {
            println("Second child throws an exception")
            throw ArithmeticException()
        }

        one.await() + two.await()
    } catch (e: ArithmeticException) {
        println("Using a default value...")
        0
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Second child throws an exception
First child was cancelled
Computation failed with ArithmeticException
```

The `try-catch` inside the `failedConcurrentSum` doesn't handle the exception thrown by `val two`.
I can convince myself that this is due to the "structured concurrency".

However, this doesn't explain why wrapping the `async`'s inside a `coroutineScope` catches the exception:

```kotlin
suspend fun failedConcurrentSum() = coroutineScope {
    try {
        val one = coroutineScope {
            async {
                try {
                    delay(1000L)
                    42
                } finally {
                    println("First child was cancelled")
                }
            }
        }

        val two = coroutineScope {
            async<Int> {
                println("Second child throws an exception")
                throw ArithmeticException()
            }
        }

        one.await() + two.await()
    } catch (e: ArithmeticException) {
        println("Using a default value...")
        0
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
First child was cancelled
Second child throws an exception
Using a default value...
0
```

Why does the latter catches an exception whereas the first doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coroutineScope` uses `Job`

> By default, a failure of any of the job’s children leads to an immediate failure of its parent and cancellation of the rest of its children.
>   [Job](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/)

You can use `supervisorScope` instead of `coroutineScope`

> A failure or cancellation of a child does not cause the supervisor job to fail and does not affect its other children.
>   [SupervisorJob](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html)

but you have to wait for the completion of the first `async` block.

Use `coroutineScope` inside `try catch` to return a default value immediately when an exception occurs

```
suspend fun failedConcurrentSum() = try {
    coroutineScope {
        val one = async {
            try {
                delay(1000L)
                42
            } finally {
                println("First child was cancelled")
            }
        }

        val two = async<Int> {
            println("Second child throws an exception")
            throw ArithmeticException()
        }

        one.await() + two.await()
    }
} catch (e: ArithmeticException) {
    println("Using a default value...")
    0
}
```

Comment: So in my second example, I could catch the exception because the inner async block cancelled the wrapping `coroutineScope`, but not the one wrapping the entire `failedConcurrentSum`, am I right?

Comment: @JayLee Yes, in the second example `async` block led to an failure only of its parent `coroutineScope` and did not affect the outer `coroutineScope`

Answer (score 3):

`coroutineScope` is just a function, it sets up its scope internally and from the outside it always completes like a regular function, not messing with any outer scopes. This is because it doesn't leak any concurrent coroutines started within its scope. You can always reliably catch and handle exceptions thrown by `coroutineScope`.

`async`, on the other hand, completes immediately after launching the coroutine, therefore you have two concurrent coroutines: one running the `async` code and another calling the corresponding `await`. Since the `async` one is also the child of the one calling `await`, its failure cancels the parent before the parent's `await` call completes.

> The try-catch inside the `failedConcurrentSum` doesn't handle the exception thrown by `val two`.

It actually does, if it gets the chance. But since the try-catch block is in a coroutine that runs concurrently to the one completing `val two`'s `Deferred`, it just doesn't get the chance to do so before being cancelled due to the failure of the child coroutine.